# Admin menu doesn't appear and simplexml_load_string() Error

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, xml

Am creating some admin manu and I have this error in logs  `Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 32: parser error : Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found  in /var/www/vhosts/domaine.com/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510` and the menu entry doesn't appear either.

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Sd_Menuadmin>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Sd_Menuadmin>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <helpers>
            <sd_menuadmin>
                <class>Sd_Menuadmin_Helper</class>
            </sd_menuadmin>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <sd_menuadmin before="Mage_Adminhtml">Sd_Menuadmin_Adminhtml</sd_menuadmin>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <sd_menu>
                    <file>sd_menu.xml</file>
                </sd_menu>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

**adminhtml.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <adminhtml>  // <- To fix the bug, do not put this tag
        <menu>
            <menu1 translate="title" module="sd_menuadmin">
                <title>Menu 1</title>
                <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                <children>
                    <menuitem1 module="sd_menuadmin">
                        <title>Submenu 1</title>
                        <action>adminhtml/menu</action>
                    </menuitem1>
                    <menuitem2 module="sd_menuadmin">
                        <title>Submenu 2</title>
                        <action>adminhtml/menu/list</action>
                    </menuitem2>
                </children>
            </menu1>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <menu1 translate="title" module="sd_menuadmin">
                            <title>Menu 1</title>
                            <sort_order>101</sort_order>
                            <children>
                                <menuitem1 module="sd_menuadmin">
                                    <title>Submenu 1</title>
                                </menuitem1>
                            </children>
                            <menuitem2 module="sd_menuadmin">
                                <title>Submenu 2</title>
                            </menuitem2>
                        </menu1>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

**Sd_Menuadmin.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Sd_Menuadmin>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Sd_Menuadmin>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**MenuController.php** in `app/code/local/Sd/Menu/controllers/Adminhtml/MenuController.php`

```
<?php

class Sd_Menuadmin_Adminhtml_MenuController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout()
            ->_setActiveMenu('mycustomtab')
            ->_title($this->__('Submenu1')); // for title

        // my stuff

        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function listAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout()
            ->_setActiveMenu('mycustomtab')
            ->_title($this->__('Submenu2')); //for title

        // my stuff

        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Comment: These two XML files look good, did you modify any other layout file? Maybe the module activation file in the `app/etc/modules` folder?

Comment: i cant find the issue, look my update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo on your `Sd_menuadmin.xml` on:
`</Sd_Menu>`. It should be `</Sd_Menuadmin>` instead.

Also, you will have to modify your adminhtml.xml file. Remove the node `<adminhtml>` and make the `<menu>` node a child of the `<config>` node. Refresh your cache. That should work.

Comment: I was wrong when I copied the code, i have well `</Sd_Menuadmin>` and it's note this issue, thank you

Comment: Okay, if you're still seeing the simplexml_load_string error, you might have modified another XML file by accident. If you're not seeing the error but your new menu isn't showing, you have to modify your `adminhtml.xml` file. Remove the node `<adminhtml>` and make the `<menu>` node a child of the `config` node. Refresh your cache. That might work.

Comment: yes the issue of menu which didn't appear is wel the <adminhtml>, please update your answer to accept it ;)